# ManagedBean no guarda datos en setters

Tags: java, jsf

estoy trabajando con un proyecto JSF en el que usamos varios ManagedBean (1 para login de usuario, otro para pre registro de usuario y el ultimo para registro de empleados)
El problema es que mi ManagedBean de login sirve perfectamente (reconoce si hay usuarios guardados) pero al pasar a la página de pre registro el managedBean encargado de guardar los datos que introduce el usuario en el formulario de pre registro no guarda nada (imprimo la variable después de ser "guardada" y no arroja ningún resultado)
Anexo fragmentos de mí código:

JSF:

```
                            <p:outputLabel value="Nombre:">
                                <p:inputText id="nombre" rendered="true" value="#{registro.nombre}"/>
                            </p:outputLabel>
                            <p:outputLabel value="Apellido Paterno:">
                                <p:inputText id="apaterno" rendered="true" value="#{registro.ap}"/>
                            </p:outputLabel>
                            <p:outputLabel value="Apellido Materno:">
                                <p:inputText id="amaterno" rendered="true" value="#{registro.am}"/>
                            </p:outputLabel>
                            <p:outputLabel value="Correo:">
                                <p:inputText id="correo" validatorMessage="Correo no valido" value="#{registro.email}">

                                    <p:clientValidator event="blur"/>
                                    <p:tooltip for="correo" value="Ingresa el Correo"/>
                                    <p:watermark for="correo" value="a@mail.com"/>
                                    <p:message for="correo" style="color: red"/>
                                </p:inputText>
                            </p:outputLabel>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                        <br/>
                        <p:commandButton value="Guardar" action="#{registro.registrar()}"/>
```

preRegistroBean:

```
    @ManagedBean(name = "registro", eager = true)
    @ApplicationScoped
    public class preRegistroBean {

        private String mySh;
        private String ap;
        private String am;
        private String nombre;
        private String email;
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
//Todos los demas getters & setters
public String registrar() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    String cadena = "";
    System.out.println(email);
    userPojo = userFacade.buscaUserstemp(email);
    if (userPojo == null) {
        String hash = generaHash();
        String numAlea = numAleatorio();
        String pwd = generaPwdTemp(numAlea);
        userPojo = new UserstempPojo(ap, am, nombre, email, pwd, hash, 0, 0);
        userFacade.crearUserTemp(userPojo);
        context.addMessage(cadena, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Se ha creado el registro, se le enviara correo", "Registrado"));
    } else {
        context.addMessage(cadena, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Ya existe un usuario con ese correo,\n solicite olvidar contraseña en index", "Error"));
    }
    return cadena;
}
```

No sé si alguien me podría ayudar a ver por qué no sirven los Setters.
Gracias y saludos.
NOTAS ADICIONALES: Al principio la clase solo tenía anotación @ManagedBean y @RequestScoped cambie a @ApplicationScoped para ver si había un cambio, pero tuvo los mismos resultados, ademas tambien anexo el commandLink que se utiliza para pasar de la pagina de login a la pagina de pre registro:

```
<p:commandLink value="Preregistro" action="Preregistro"/>
```

EDIT: Subo tambien el xhtml completo de la pagina de preregistro:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
```

```
<f:view contentType="text/html">
    <h:head>
        <f:facet name="first">
            <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
            <ui:define name="titulo"/>
        </f:facet>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <ui:composition template="Templates/Master.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="header">
                <ui:include src="/Templates/headerDos.xhtml"/>
            </ui:define>
            <ui:define name="izquierdo">
                <ui:include src="/Templates/izquierdoOtro.xhtml"/>
            </ui:define>
            <ui:define name="content">
                <h:form>
                    <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true"/>
                    <div align="center">
                        <h2>Preregistro</h2>
                        <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="10">
                            <p:outputLabel value="Nombre:">
                                <p:inputText id="nombre" rendered="true" value="#{registro.nombre}"/>
                            </p:outputLabel>
                            <p:outputLabel value="Apellido Paterno:">
                                <p:inputText id="apaterno" rendered="true" value="#{registro.ap}"/>
                            </p:outputLabel>
                            <p:outputLabel value="Apellido Materno:">
                                <p:inputText id="amaterno" rendered="true" value="#{registro.am}"/>
                            </p:outputLabel>
                            <p:outputLabel value="Correo:">
                                <p:inputText id="correo" validatorMessage="Correo no valido" value="#{registro.email}">

                                    <p:clientValidator event="blur"/>
                                    <p:tooltip for="correo" value="Ingresa el Correo"/>
                                    <p:watermark for="correo" value="a@mail.com"/>
                                    <p:message for="correo" style="color: red"/>
                                </p:inputText>
                            </p:outputLabel>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                        <br/>
                        <p:commandButton value="Guardar" action="#{registro.registrar()}"/>

                    </div>
                    <!--<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcOITgUAAAAAKVljosN9opvihgMsQ_ZvzMzT_rK"></div>-->
                </h:form>
            </ui:define>
            <ui:define name="footer"/>
        </ui:composition>

    </h:body>
</f:view>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes copiar el xhtml completo?

Comment: Listo, edite el post ya con el xhtml completo, gracias

Comment: No veo nada raro, ¿puedes quitar el validador del campo email y ver si así funciona? Por descartar que sea un error al validar.